# some properties elements disappeared

Tags: android, properties, element

I am new in android studio
I was working on it with oe problem but suddenly I found that I am not able to find all properties elements as it shown in pic attached.
I think it is not a code problem.
This is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us the relevant code or error messages here instead of using external links.

Comment: ok , that done by mistake sorry